# Tensorflow summary scalars not showing up in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have used tensorboard in several projects previously and it has worked great. When I run those projects now it still works. However, in a new project the summary scalars I have saved will not show up. The graph is there and appears correct but the "No scalar data was found" dialogue is under the scalars tab. I tried to write the simplest code I could think of as a test and it's still not working:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():

    y = tf.Variable(1)
    initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    tf.summary.scalar('thing',y)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g)
sess.run(initialize)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("path",g)

for i in range(10):
    summary = sess.run(merged)
    writer.add_summary(summary,i)

sess.close()
```

I'm thinking this should just give me a constant y value over 10 steps, but no scalars in tensorboard. Have I made some mistake?

Comment: When you call `merged = tf.summary.merge_all()`, you are creating ops in the *current* default graph instead of `g`, which is empty. So the `merged` should be a no-op.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Siyuan. How would it look for merged to be a no-op?

Comment: You could `print` the `summary` variable to see if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the graph definition to:

```
with g.as_default():
  y = tf.Variable(1)
  tf.summary.scalar('thing', y)
  initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

I.e., first define a summary op, then the initialization op. This way it appears on tensorboard:

[image: tensorboard]

It's also possible that the summary wasn't flushed, in this case `writer.flush()` will help.

Comment: This does not make things appear in tensorboard as far as I can tell.